Why $%7Bid%7D is been showing and saying id has assigned a value but never used
Here in this code my id is not showing assigned.
when i click for tourdetails, i got $%7Bid%7D instead of id. how to fix it? as the id not assigned from here, it is not showing any of those
const TourCard = ({tour}) => {

  const{id, title, city, photo, price, featured, reviews } = tour;
   
   const{totalRating, avgRating}= calculateAvgRating(reviews);

  return (
    <div className="tour__card">
      <Card>
        <div className="tour__img">
            <img src={photo} alt="tour-img"/>
            {featured && <span>Featured</span>}
        </div>
      </Card>

        <CardBody>
        <div className="card__top d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <span className="tour__location d-flex align-items-center gap-1">
            <i class="ri-map-pin-line"></i> {city}
        </span>
        <span className="tour__rating d-flex align-items-center gap-1">
            <i class="ri-star-fill"></i> {avgRating === 0? null: avgRating} 
            {totalRating === 0? ( 'Not Rated' ): <span>({reviews.length})</span>}
            
        </span>
        </div>

        <h5 className="tour__title">
          <Link to = {'/tours/${id}'}>{title}</Link>
          </h5> 

        <div className="card__bottom d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-3">
            <h5>${price}<span>/ per person</span></h5>
            
            <button className='btn booking__btn'>
                <Link to = {'/tours/${id}'}>Book Now</Link>
            </button>

        </div>
      </CardBody>
     
     
    </div>
  );
};

export default TourCard;

const{id, title, city, photo, price, featured, reviews } = tour;

 <h5 className="tour__title">
          <Link to = {'/tours/${id}'}>{title}</Link>
 </h5> 

<button className='btn booking__btn'>
<Link to = {'/tours/${id}'}>Book Now</Link>
</button>


<Link to = {'/tours/${id}'}>{title}</Link>

The expression in the outer braces, {'/tours/${id}'}, is a normal JavaScript expression and your use of single quotes like ' does not allow ${id} to be substituted. If you change to backticks (`), then JavaScript treats it as a template string and substitutes the ID as needed.
<Link to = {`/tours/${id}`}>{title}</Link>

Remember that template strings and JSX curly braces might look similar but are actually handled through different processes at different times. The ${ is a good signal of the template literal and only happens within backticks (`).

tnq so much bro
